Question regarding 0-ary relations
EDIT-
Definition. A denotes a unary relation iff
∀x[if x∈ A then ∃y[x= (y)]]
Using this definition, since individuals don't contain elements, any individual is a unary relation.  Since the empty set contains no elements, ∅ denotes a unary relation.  Now, suppose you are using a free logic, so that a constant might not denote anything.  Then, if you are faced with the expression C ∈A, you can't use existential generalization to infer ∃x[x∈A].  However, if you use the definition of a unary relation then you have:
A denotes a unary relation iff
∀x[if x ∈A then ∃y[y∈A]]
Now if ∃y[y∈A] then A denotes a set.  Therefore
A denotes a unary relation iff
∀x[if x ∈A then A denotes a set]
So, suppose A denotes a non-empty set.  Then, since the consequent is true, the conditional as a whole is true, so that A denotes a unary relation.  Thus, all sets are unary relations, but not all unary relations are sets.  Individuals are unary relations, but individuals aren't sets.
Thus, my idea of using 0-ary relations to denote individuals might be a bad idea.  Individuals are a kind of 1-ary relation.  Thus, I don't need to place individual constants in the alphabet since I have predicate constants that denote unary relations.  So what I need to know is can I prove individuals are 0-ary relations?
My best idea to prove that individuals are 0-ary relations is to define a nullary (0-ary) relation as follows.
Definition. A is a nullary relation iff ∀x[x∉A]
Since individuals don't contain elements, every individual is a nullary relation by this definition.  Also, the empty set is a nullary relation.

I am developing General Order Logic, which is intended to subsume all consistent logics.  I obviously need to specify the alphabet for GOL.  In Irving M. Copi's 'Symbolic Logic' his alphabet for first order logic is as follows:

Infinitely many capital letters from the first part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts:

A, B, C,A1,  B1, C1, A2,  B2, C2, ...
These are propositional constants, and on the system's intended interpretation will be noncompound statements.

Infinitely many capital letters from the middle part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts:

P, Q, R,P1,  Q1, R1, P2,  Q2, R2, ...
These are propositional variables, and on the system's intended interpretation will designate propositions.

Infinitely many capital letters from the first part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts having right-hand superscripts '1', '2', '3',....

A1, B1, C1, A11, B11, C11,  A21, B21, C21,...
These are predicate constants, and on the system's intended interpretation each of them will designate a particular attribute or binary or ternary or n-ary relation according as its right superscript is a '1', '2', '3', or... or 'n'.

Infinitely many capital letters from the middle part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts having right-hand superscripts '1', '2', '3',....

P1, Q1, R1, P11, Q11, R11,  P21, Q21, R21,...
These are predicate variables, and on the system's intended interpretation will be symbols for which names of particular attributes, binary relations, and so forth can be instantiated.

Infinitely many lowercase letters from the first part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts:

a, b, c,a1,  b1, c1, a2,  b2, c2, ...
These are individual constants, and on the system's intended interpretation will be proper names of individuals.

Infinitely many lowercase letters from the latter part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts:

x, y, z,x1,  y1, z1, x2,  y2, z2, ...
These are individual variables, and on the system's intended interpretation will be symbols which are to be instantiated by individual constants.

Just four additional symbols complete the list of primitive symbols for FOL:

~, ∧, (, )
Now Copi did not include 0-ary relation symbols.  So in the interest of brevity, I was thinking of defining 0-ary relation symbols as individuals, and regarding propositions merely as a kind of individual.
Thus the alphabet for GOL, would consist purely of predicate constants, and predicate variables, and logical symbols. Sets would be 1-ary relations.
So my questions are, can all individuals be regarded as 0-ary relations, and can all propositions be regarded as a kind of individual?

I don't see the difference between a 0-ary operator and a constant, except you fool around with the existential operator ∃.  Looks like lambda-calc's treatment of constants as functions.

Why do you start with defining individuals as 1-ary relations and then ask if they can be 0-ary relations? None of the question before the last sentence seems relevant to the question itself.

@DavidGudeman, I never defined individuals.  I merely noticed that any individual is a 1-ary relation.  A nullary relation is a unary relation, so it's possible individuals are nullary and unary relations.   If you read carefully you see I suggest a definition of a nullary relation, in which any individual is a nullary relation.  As for the part before the last sentence,  that motivates the question.  I'm working out the most general logic, and I want to reduce the kinds of constants and variables Copi uses for classical FOL.  He has propositional constants, and I want to treat them as

individual constants.  Also he introduced a set of individual constants, and I want to treat them as predicate constants that denote 0-ary relations.  This is a simplification over Copi's presentation.

"Null" means zero, not one. A nullary relation is a 0-ary relation. A unary relation is a 1-ary relation.

@DavidGudeman, I found the following at Wikipedia.
Unary
Unary (1-ary) relations can be viewed as a collection of members (such as the collection of Nobel laureates) having some property (such as that of having been awarded the Nobel prize).
Every nullary function is a unary relation.  THEREFORE IF R IS A NULLARY RELATION THEN R IS A UNARY RELATION.

That makes no sense. If a nullary function is a unary relation how does that make a nullary relation a unary relation?

A function is a relation.  So i inferred that some, perhaps all, nullary relations are unary relations.

You can represent individuals as 0-ary functions, but not 0-ary relations. A 0-ary function would be a function that takes no parameters and returns exactly one value, so you can represent an individual with the 0-ary function that returns that individual.
A 0-ary relations would be a relation that takes no arguments and is always either true or false, so 0-ary relations can only represent two individuals: true and false. There is one 0-ary relation that represents true and one that represents false.
Ironically, you can represent an individual with a 1-ary relation, although not using your definition of a 1-ary relation. Given any individual, you can represent that individual with the 1-ary relation that is true only of that individual. However, not all 1-ary relations would then represent an individual.

From Wikipedia: Under the closed-world assumption, an n-ary relation is interpreted as the extension of some n-adic predicate: all and only those n-tuples whose values, substituted for corresponding free variables in the predicate, yield propositions that hold true, appear in the relation. A zero-degree relation is therefore interpreted as the extension of the 0-adic predicate P() → true.  BUT I DON'T WANT TO USE THE CLOSED WORLD ASSUMPTION.  I want to define a nullary relation as A is a nullary relation iff for all x[ not(x is an element of A)].  Can I or can't I do that?

+1 Well spoken. For the OP, 0-ary is just a constant.
